# How to use in memory and redis cache in the same project?

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, in-memory

Have two classes, both annotating with `@Cacheable` (`org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`), either methods or class. I think it doesn't matter for this question.

Example:

```
@Cacheable(value = STATE_CACHE_NAME, key = "#root.methodName + '-' + #country?.id ?: \"null\" + '-' + #stateName ?: \"null\"")
public Long getStateId(CountryEntity country, String stateName) {...}
```

In some classes I'd like to use the simple in-memory cache and others the Redis cache. Both are configured in Spring boot auto-configure `CacheConfigurations`. How do I state this intent and use the different configurations?

Answer (score 2):

`@Cacheable` takes a parameter "cacheManager", which lets you specify which bean of `CacheManager` it refers to.

So you'd add it with the **name of the bean** of your wanted `CacheManager`.

```java
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "inMemoryCache", value = STATE_CACHE_NAME, key = "#root.methodName + '-' + #country?.id ?: \"null\" + '-' + #stateName ?: \"null\"")
public Long getStateId(CountryEntity country, String
```

You can either use the name of the bean method, or provide the name via the "name" parameter of `@Bean`.

E.g.

```java
@Bean(name = "inMemoryCache")
CacheManager cacheManager() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. This solution requires me to create a specific instance of an in-memory cache in the method implementation. I'd like to use an autowired version of the in-memory cache, like I do with Redis.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I'm not sure I'm getting what you mean, can you edit your question with more details?

Comment: @david-gomez, updated the question and upvoted as it's still a valueble answer.